# is not assignable to type IntrinsicAttributes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'am working on a next.js project where i pass data from getStaticProps to the main component and when i try to pass it to the children i get an error saying that the data i try to pass are not assignable: here is the code:

the data :

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  let articlesArray: articleCard[] = []
  const data = await getArticlesList().then((response) => {
    return response
  })
  if (data) {
    articlesArray.push(...data)
  }
  return {
    props: {
      articlesArray
    }
  }
}
```

Then i get it in the main component:

```
export default function Blog(props: { articlesArray: articleCard[] }) {
  const articlesList = props.articlesArray
  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <ArticleList articleList={articlesList} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

then the component that will use the data:

```
function ArticleList({articleList}: articleCard[]) {
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState<number>(1)
  const [articlesPerPage] = useState<number>(6)

return (
       <h1> rest of the code </h1>
       )
}
```

for info:
the cardArticle type is as follows:

```
export interface fields {
  title: string
  slug: string
  content: [Object]
  excerpt: string
  coverImage: [Object]
  date: string
  author: [Object]
  categories: []
}
export interface articleCard extends fields {
  id: string
}
```

the errors:
at **ArticleList**: Property 'articleList' does not exist on type 'articleCard[]'.

at **Blog** on the ArticleList component:
Type '{ articleList: articleCard[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & articleCard[]'.
Property 'articleList' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & articleCard[]'.

Comment: Looks like a typo, try: `{articleList}: {articleList: articleCard[]}`.

Comment: @Dogbert, looks like it was... i'm speechless. thank you